# How to turn off reset position on blender?

Tags: pose-mode

I'm having an issue with the posing mode in blender, I imported a blender file that i downloaded and I can't pose it because "rest position" is on and I can't figure out how to turn that off.

Answer (score 2):

In the *Data* panel, under *Pose*, click on *Pose Position*:

[image]